# Difference between iTunes Connect accounts/roles and Apple Developer account

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, code-signing, apple-developer

I'm very confused by how Apple handles this. Here is my situation:

Im a solo IOS developer with a paid Apple Developer account. I can access iTunes connect and upload apps there, this works fine. I pick "manage signing automatically" in XCode using "IOS Developer" Code Signing identity.

So this works.

An organization Im working for invited me in iTunes connect. So I can create apps for them on them too. Now I have two things on my account there.

How can I upload an app for their account? I cant seem to transfer an existing app and I cant seem to sign it with an identity which matches their profile/account/whatever.

Comment: If the organization only invited you to iTunes connect, you can't automatically login to their developer portal at developer.apple.com. They need to add your user to the portal as well. iTunes Connect is for distributing apps, while the Developer portal handles signing etc.

Comment: Thanks, Im gonna check what they see on their developer page. Can you tell me about certificates? Will I see it automatically in xCode?

Answer (score 1):

The process appears confusing but actually it isn't. Lets walk through it:

First you create an AppleID. You then use that AppleID to register for a Developer program. Registering to a developer program gives access to two types of accounts. Or rather say that you are provided with the access to two different portals for the same account. One is developer portal and other is iTunes Connect. For background work like registering an AppID, testing devices and managing certificates and profiles you use Developer Portal. For frontend work like creating an app to be published to the AppStore, uploading your build, distributing it for testing you use iTunes Connect portal.

Now if you are being invited by some other organisation in its developer program with the same AppleID, you have two accounts linked to the same AppleID. Now when you login to the developer portal you are logged in to the one account automatically and you can change to the other by selected from a dropdown at the top right. Once you have selected the organisation you then continue working same when you worked previously with a single account.

Here is the screenshot of my developer dashboard with multiple accounts:

[image]
Hope this clarifies.

Comment: Thanks, but I cannot switch on developer.apple.com, I only see myself. On iTunes connect I see the organization which invited me, and there is a dropdown there.

Comment: try login through developer.apple.com.

Comment: @breakline Edited the answer with developer.apple.com login. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but thats what I meant. I dont see anything but myself on developer.apple.com. I see the organization on the separate iTunes connect site.

Comment: Oh. Got it. What I believe is that there might be some role that restricts you from accessing the developer portal but you can access the iTunes connect account of the company. This is the reason you can see organisation switch menu in iTunes Connect but not on developer.apple.com.

Comment: I belive they gave me "Admin" role on iTunes connect. I can create apps there. Is there anything else I can tell them? Is there a separate access for the developer portal?

Comment: According to the Apple documentation there are total 3 roles. Agent, Admin and Member. Agent is the most privileged. Admin is almost the replica of Agent. Member is less privileged and used for inviting developers in a team.

Comment: Check this link for further clarification:
https://developer.apple.com/support/roles/

Comment: Thanks gonna take a look

Comment: You might want to change this to App Store Connect as the branding has changed. Roles are listed here at this time: https://itunespartner.apple.com/en/apps/faq/Users%20and%20Roles_Overview and https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/deve5f9a89d7

Answer (score 0):

The team agent can initiate the app transfer.
**Steps:**

1. My Apps
2. Select your app
3. Scroll to the Additional Information section
   and click Transfer App, then click Done.

   [image: See this]

See more details on app transfer [here](https://help.apple.com/itunes-connect/developer/#/deved688524f)

To sign an app you need provisioning profile and signing entity (.p12 file)
Or **Apple Developer Account** access from where you can generate certs and provisioning profile and download

After getting signing identity and provisioning profile from Apple Developer Account perform following steps

1. Archive App
2. Open Organiser (Xcode >> Window >> Organiser)
3. Select app and version you want to upload
4. Click Upload to App Store and follow instructions

[image: 3]]

Comment: Thanks, but I cant see the "Transfer App" option

Comment: @breakline This option is visible for Agent only, Even admin don't have those permissions.